# Why my window function isn't removing harmonics?

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing, spectrogram

I have been working on creating a mixed wave signal. My code is in c++ :

**Server signal:**

```
    void server_sineWave(BitDepth buffer[], double sin_freq, double beep_freq) {

    BitDepth amplitude = std::numeric_limits<BitDepth>::max() * 0.5;
    QWORD c = 0;
    double d = (samplerate / sin_freq);

    int initial = NUM_SAMPLES / 25;

    for (QWORD i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i += channels) {

        buffer[i] = amplitude * sin((2 * pi * sin_freq * i) / samplerate); // sin wave generated at "freq"

        if (i == initial) {
            for (QWORD j = 0; j < 480; j++) {
                double stream = amplitude * sin((2 * pi * sin_freq * i / samplerate));
                double beep = amplitude * sin((2 * pi * beep_freq * j / samplerate));
                double multiplier = .4 * (1 - cos(2 * pi * j / 480));

                buffer[i] = stream + (beep * multiplier);
                i++;
            }

            initial = i + 19200.0;
        }
    }
  }
```

**Client signal:**

```
    void client_sineWave(BitDepth buffer[], double sin_freq, double beep_freq) {

    BitDepth amplitude = std::numeric_limits<BitDepth>::max() * 0.5;
    QWORD c = 0;
    double d = (samplerate / sin_freq);

    int initial = NUM_SAMPLES / 25;

    for (QWORD i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i += channels) {

        buffer[i] = amplitude * sin(2 * pi * sin_freq * i / samplerate); // sin wave generated at "freq"

        if (i == initial) {
            for (QWORD j = 0; j < 480; j++) {
                double stream = amplitude * sin((2 * pi * sin_freq * i / samplerate));
                double beep = amplitude * sin((2 * pi * beep_freq * j / samplerate));
                double multiplier = .4 * (1 - cos(2 * pi * j / 480));

                buffer[i] = stream + (beep * multiplier);
//                buffer[i] += (beep * multiplier);
                i++;
            }

            initial = i + 19200.0;


            //(1000 + rand() % 10000)
            //double deg = 360.0 / d;
            //buffer[i] = buffer[i + (1 * (channels - 1))] = sin((c++ * deg) * pi / 180) * amplitude;
        }
    }
}
```

**Mixing of server and client signals:**

```
    void mix(BitDepth buffer[], BitDepth server[], BitDepth client[], double duration_milliseconds) {

    QWORD num_samples = duration_milliseconds * (NUM_SAMPLES / 10000.0);

    double tmp = 0;

    QWORD size = NUM_SAMPLES + num_samples;

    BitDepth *server_delay = new BitDepth[size];
    BitDepth *client_delay = new BitDepth[size];

    for (QWORD i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i < num_samples) {
            server_delay[i] = 0;
            client_delay[i + NUM_SAMPLES] = 0;

        }
        if (i > num_samples) {
            server_delay[i] = server[i - num_samples];
            client_delay[i - num_samples] = client[i - num_samples];
        }

    }

    for (QWORD i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i += channels) {

//        double multiplier = .5 * (1 - cos(2 * pi * i / NUM_SAMPLES-1));
//        double multiplier = (0.54 - 0.46 * cos(2.0 * M_PI * (double) i / (double) (NUM_SAMPLES - 1)));


//        server_delay[i] = multiplier * (server_delay[i]);
//        client_delay[i] = multiplier * (client_delay[i]);

        tmp = server_delay[i] + client_delay[i];

        if (tmp > 32767) {
            tmp = 32767;
        } else if (tmp < -32768) {
            tmp = -32768;
        }

        buffer[i] = tmp;


    }
}
```

**My Result in spectrogram from the above code:**

[image]

Now, when I change the amplitude by increasing value from 0.5 to 0.8, in the following line:

```
BitDepth amplitude = std::numeric_limits<BitDepth>::max() * 0.5;
```

to

```
BitDepth amplitude = std::numeric_limits<BitDepth>::max() * 0.8;
```

I get following result:

[image]

I am new in DSP c++ programming and I really don't know what is this issue and how to resolve this issue?
Please help me in solving this issue.
thanks.

Comment: Your waveform is clipping (because 0.8 + 0.8 > 1.0), which will generate a lot of harmonics - look at the data in your debugger and you’ll see lots of flat peaks at +/- 32k.

Comment: Thanks @PaulR, let me change the value and update you after that..

Comment: Thanks @PaulR. Its resolved now. Thanks alot

Comment: You’re welcome - glad to hear it’s resolved.

Answer (score 1):

As Suggested by @PaulR, clipping was causing a lot of harmonics.

> Your waveform is clipping (because 0.8 + 0.8 > 1.0), which will generate a lot of harmonics - look at the data in your debugger and you’ll see lots of flat peaks at +/- 32k.

So, after taking care of this limit. My issue is resolved.

Thanks alot.